# Mathematica isn't sure whether a sum of two positives is positive or not

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica is not able to tell whether a summation of two positive expressions is positive or not. Which is very strange.

My three symbolic arguments, $x$, $y$, and $z$, are all real numbers bounded by zero and one. Hence the following expression should definitely be positive as well.

$x + (1 - x) (1 + y)^z$

My code is:

```
$Assumptions = {(x | y | z) \[Element] Reals} && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 && 0 < z < 1

Refine[x + (1 - x) (1 + y)^z > 0]
```

The expected result is `True`. But what I get is just a repetition of the inequality within `Refine`.

To test, I tried the two terms on LHS separately as:

```
Refine[x > 0]

Refine[(1 - x) (1 + y)^z > 0]
```

And both give me `True`. But once I combine them it doesn't work. This is very very strange.

Can anyone help me out? Thank you so much!

Comment: `Refine[ x + (1 - x) (1 + y)^z >= x >= 0, 
 Element[{x, y, z}, Reals] && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 && 0 < z < 1]` :D

Comment: @belisarius Why is this answer a comment ???

Comment: @eldo Basically becuse I don't fully understand what is happening there

Comment: Simpler examples that fail to be `Refine`-d: `1 - x + x^x > 0`, `1 - x + x^1. > 0`, `2 x - x^1. > 0`.  OTOH, `Refine` fails on `x^x - x > 0`, which seems less elementary but may have to do with why (some) others fail: `Power` is a transcendental function in this case.  (Sorry, it's basically a guess, and I can't explain further.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although I don't know exactly why `Refine` fails in this example, `Reduce` can often help when simpler methods fail. Here, I feed it the desired statement *together* with the assumptions which are specified in `Assuming`:

```
statement = x + (1 - x) (1 + y)^z > 0;

Assuming[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 && 0 < z < 1,
 Refine[Reduce[$Assumptions && statement]]
 ]

(* ==> True *)
```

After `Reduce` reformulates the statement, `Refine` is able to deduce the desired result. I omitted the reality assumption because it's already implicit in the inequalities.

Comment: While this shows me some way to circumvent the problem, the initial issue remains. So maybe this is what Mathematica developers need to seriously address?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. My actual inequality is much more complicated than the one used here. And for that inequality, your solution does not work while it does work for the simpler inequality used here. Is there any alternative approach? Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @jim Since I don't know what prevents `Refine` from working, it will be very hard to give a general cure for this problem. Here is another idea: see if you get an empty set by applying `Assuming[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1 && 0 < z < 1, 
 FindInstance[$Assumptions && Not[statement], {x, y, z}]]`. That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: @ Jens I see.. Maybe I should contact Wolfram and talk directly to their technicians... I really appreciate though!

Answer (score 5):

Forgive me if this is not useful but sometimes I find value in using [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) in such problems:

```
x = y = z = Interval[{0, 1}];

x + (1 - x) (1 + y)^z
```

> ```
> Interval[{0, 3}]
> ```

`Interval` represents a closed interval rather than the open intervals in your example so this is *not* equivalent, nevertheless it may help to find the bounds of an expression.